# How to use random numbers that executes a one dimensional random walk in python?

Tags: python, random

Start with a one dimensional space of length m, where m = 2 * n + 1. Take a step either to the left or to the right at random, with equal probability. Continue taking random steps until you go off one edge of the space, for which I'm using while 0 <= position < m.

We have to write a program that executes the random walk. We have to create a 1D space using size n = 5 and place the marker in the middle. Every step, move it either to the left or to the right using the random number generator. There should be an equal probability that it moves in either direction.

I have an idea for the plan but do not know how to write it in python:

- Initialize n = 1, m = 2n + 1, and j = n + 1.
- Loop until j = 0 or j = m + 1 as shown. At each step:

  - Move j left or right at random.
  - Display the current state of the walk, as shown.
- Make another variable to count the total number of steps.

  - Initialize this variable to zero before the loop.
  - However j moves always increase the step count.
- After the loop ends, report the total steps.

Comment: You need to try first. This site is great for helping you to improve your code, or help you find bugs, but we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Do you want to do statistical analysis?

Comment: @RobAnthony I edited my post and put a plan. can you please look at it?

Answer (score 1):

- 1 - Start with a list initialized with 5 items (maybe `None`?)
- 2 - place the walker at index 2
- 3 - randomly chose a direction (-1 or + 1)
- 4 - move the walker in the chosen direction
- 5 - maybe print the space and mark the location of the walker
- 6 - repeat at step 3 as many times as needed